# Thin Foreman stopped working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thin, foreman

I'm using Thin webserver with RoR on my iMac.
I start it with $ foreman start

It was working fine, but now I'm getting this in the console:

```
09:27:10 web.1     | => Booting Thin
09:27:10 web.1     | => Rails 3.1.3 application starting in development on     http://0.0.0.0:5000
09:27:10 web.1     | => Call with -d to detach
09:27:10 web.1     | => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
09:27:10 web.1     | >> Thin web server (v1.3.1 codename Triple Espresso)
09:27:10 web.1     | >> Maximum connections set to 1024
09:27:10 web.1     | >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:5000, CTRL+C to stop
09:27:10 web.1     | Exiting
09:27:11 web.1     | process terminated
09:27:11 system    | sending SIGTERM to all processes
```

And the $ prompt shows up - so the webserver isn't running.

Any ideas?

I just ran $ thin start
and got:

> > Using rack adapter
> >     /Users/burtondav/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:31:in `block in setup': You have already activated rack 1.4.1, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.3.6. Using bundle exec may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)

What bundle exec command should I try?

Comment: I think it means 'bundle exec thin start' .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `gem 'thin'` in your application `Gemfile` and execute the `bundle exec thin start` to resolve the version conflict problem.

Comment: If I enter $ bundle exec thin start, the thin webserver starts and my app is running in localhost:3000 - before, I could enter $ foreman start and it would run in localhost:5000

Comment: My foreman proc file has: web: bundle exec rails server thin -p $PORT

Comment: The default port number used by foreman is `5000` for the first service. You can reference the document for more details [http://ddollar.github.com/foreman/](http://ddollar.github.com/foreman/). You can pass the option `-p 5000` when you run manually.